# Particular name for the diagonal matrix with only one non-zero components

Tags: matrices, terminology

I need to deal with such matrices who are diagonal and with only one non-zero component. But, how should I call them?

e.g,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$$, $$B=\begin{bmatrix}0& 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I think you could describe it as sparse for having mostly zero entries but that doesn't address the solitary one.

Comment: Yeah, difficult to name.

Comment: They're also 0-1 matrices and projections, but that doesn't really help. You may have to make up a name, especially if this is for a paper.

Comment: Yes, it's for a paper, but still want a catchy name.

Comment: They're called [diagonal binary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix). **Edit:** I just realised your matrices have exactly one $1$, so what I suggested doesn't work. There are ways to describe them using standard terminology, but they're aren't exactly short.

Comment: Could I call it `outer product of standard basis`?

Answer (score 0):

A diagonal matrix is defined to be a matrix such that any non-diagonal entry is $0$. For these matrices $A$ and $B$, all non-diagonal entries are $0$. So, these are also diagonal.

If its any help, the $0$ matrix is also by definition diagonal. I am unaware of any other particular name for this type of matrix. Although you could call these matrices singular or non invertible as well if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not a clear answer to describe such a special matrix.

Comment: I mean there's many ways you can come up with. Call it a diagonal matrix with one non-zero eigenvalue of multiplicity 1.

Comment: Thx, still not a perfect name.

Comment: Could I call it `outer product of standard basis`?